# Access User with Account Id

Tags: apex, soql, query, user, person-accounts

I'm trying to access the User field Email via the related Account Id. I use this query in my controller :

```
User currentUser = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE AccountId=:accountId LIMIT 1];
```

But when I try to view the page it sends me an error :

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject

The Account Id exist because when I use a qury like this it works :

```
Account acc = [SELECT Id, PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId]
```

(but this is not what I want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the `Account` record exists does not mean any `User` records look up to it. A more appropriate methodology for querying records whose existence is not known is to use list assignment.

```
List<User> candidates = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE ... LIMIT 1];
if (!candidates.isEmpty()) currentUser = candidates[0];
```